# Stationary solutions of the Cauchy PDE problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, continuity, characteristics

> Consider $$\partial_{t}u -y\partial_{x}u +x\partial_{y}u = 0$$ in $t>0, (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, with initial condition $$ u(0,x,y) =
>  u_{0}(x,y) $$ for $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Find the stationary solutions (no dependence on $t$) and discuss their physical intepretation.

My attempt: Suppose a solution $u$ is stationary. Then $\partial_{t}u = 0$, so the PDE becomes
$$-y\partial_{x}u +x\partial_{y}u = 0.$$ We can solve by using the method of characteristics which gives us the equations:

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{ds} &= -y, \\
\frac{dy}{ds} &= x, \\
\frac{du}{ds} &= 0.
\end{align}

From here I am unsure. The first two equations can be solved to give $x=A\cos(s) +B\sin(s)$ and $y=C\cos(s) +D\sin(s)$, and we also get that $u(s) = \rm constant$. How can we proceed?

Comment: You could also use polar coordinates, since $-y u_x + x u_y$ is proportional to the the directional derivative of $u$ in the angular direction.

Comment: For information. The general solution of the PDE is : $$u(t,x,y)=F\left( (x^2+y^2)\:,\: (\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)-t)\right)$$ Or equivalently in polar coordinates $\big(x=\rho \cos(\theta)\:;\:y=\rho\sin(\theta)\big)$ : $$u(t,\rho,\theta)=\Phi\big(\rho,(\theta-t)\big)$$ $F$ and $\Phi$ are arbitrary functions of two arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $y=-x'$ gives
$$
y=A\sin(s)-B\cos(s),
$$
so that in fact there are only two coefficients involved.

It means that $u$ is constant on circles $x^2+y^2=r^2=A^2+B^2$. Or $u_0(x,y)=f_0(r)$. The only condition that I see is that $f_0\in C^1$ and $f_0'(0)=0$.